# optimising for index of pair in an array whose sum is given

Tags: c, arrays

I am coding for finding all the indexes of pair of numbers in an array whose sum is already given.

```
for(i=0;i<max;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<max;j++)
    {
        if(a[i]+a[j]==sum)
            printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
    }
}
```

where max is maximum size of array. And sum is the sum of pair of numbers.(There could be repetition of values in the array.)

But I get only this naive O(n^2) solution. Can anyone help me out in getting best solution possible for this case.

Comment: you could make this considerably more efficient if the sequence were sorted first.

Comment: You can do it in `O(n)` time if it's sorted

Comment: @WhozCraig if i sort them how could i get back the original index in the given array?

Comment: @user3160274 so don't sort them, sort a pointer or index array targeting the original elements. Sorting a sequence `ar[N]` indirectly by sorting `idx[N]`, where the "value" of each `idx[i]` is `ar[idx[i]]`. When finished the original sequence is untouched. Iow, its doable, just a little more work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Sort your array.  **O(nlg(n))**
- for each `i` in your array **O(n)**, to a binary search for `sum-i` **O(lg(n))** for a total of **O(nlg(n))**

That's 2 operations for **O(nlg(n))**, for a total of **O(nlg(n))**

Comment: In the second step you can be much faster than doing a binary search.

Comment: @hivert the second step doesn't increase the time complexity

Comment: IF you can put a constraint on the size of the numbers, you can probably go **O(n)**

Comment: I got to print out the positions and not the values. So once I sort the array, how could i get back the the indexes of those values in original array?

Comment: user3160274: You make an array of pairs `(value, pos)` and sort those pairs according to the value. C is not the easiest language to do that.

Comment: @user3160274 you can make an array of tuples/objects `{index, value}` or you can also have another array of indices(starting from 0 to n-1), and sort that in parallel with your values array

Comment: @user3160274 there are a bunch of well-known sorting algorithms.  All I mean by "paralell" sorting is that every time you change the values array, you change the indices array in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

If your array is sorted you can have linear complexity:

```
j = max-1
for (i=0; i<j; i++) {
    while (a[i] + a[j] > sum and j>i) j--;
    if  (a[i] + a[j] == sum) printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but what if array is not sorted?

Comment: @user3160274 than sort it